# Pattern for matching date followed by string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string with the repeating pattern of the form

`MM/DD/YYYY (FirstName LastName) Status Update: blah blah blah blah`

E.G.

```
string test = "11/01/2011 (Joe Bob) Status Update: Joe is the collest guy on earfth 08/07/2010 (Rach Mcadam) Status Update: whatever I dont care 06/28/2009 (Some Guy) Status Update: More junk and note how I end there's not gonna be another date after me"
```

How can I group match this so as to have Date, Name, and Status update for each match?

I tried

```
        string datePattern = "\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{0,4}";
        string personPattern = "\\(\\w*\\)";
        Regex regex = new Regex("(" + datePattern + ") (" + personPattern + ") (.*)");
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(test);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("##Match Found##");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0]);//full text
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);//date only
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2]);//person
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[3]);//note
        }
```

It's pulling back nothing at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spaces aren't included in `\w`, so `\w*` will not match `Joe Bob`.  Try changing `personPattern` to `"\\([ \\w]*\\)"`.

It also looks like your regex is too greedy, because the `.*` at the end will match the rest of the string, instead of stopping at the next date.  Try changing your regex to the following:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(" + datePattern + ") (" + personPattern + ") (.*?(?=$|" + datePattern + "))");
```

Comment: This only tells me how to get some results rather than no results.  Yes I have a name and a date, but all the dates are not splitup.  This just gives me a blob similar to all the other variations I've come up with myself.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Not sure I understand what you mean, you should have a separate group for each of the fields you are interested in, and the date should be in `match.Groups[1]`.

Comment: Please try it using the code I posted in the question and see if it works as described. I expect a result split into rows and columns like a DB Table

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey - Ahh got it, the `.*` at the end was the issue, because it was matching to the end of the string.  Just edited my answer, give it a try.